# How can I get Rhythmbox to see my Ubuntu One purchases?

Tags: 11.10, music, rhythmbox, ubuntu-one

I have purchased a couple of albums in the Ubuntu one music store which have downloaded and are visible in the default music app Banshee. I much prefer the app Rhythmbox though, but I can't figure out how to tell Rhythmbox to scan for music purchases.

It doesn't see them automatically, and because the folder is hidden, I don't even know where they are. I don't want to have to move the files around just to make them available to Rhythmbox. Would be much nicer if Rhythmbox could just scan the right folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Home Folder and press Ctrl and h on your keyboard. Your purchased music is in the ".ubuntuone" folder. You can then import the folder manually using Music > Import Folder command. I haven't found a way to import automatically yet. I'll keep looking.

I found this in the Help Section of Rhythmbox.... (If you want to add more than one folder to watch, use gconf-editor and add it to the list /app/rhythmbox/library_locations) I haven't tried it yet to see if it works.